# How kill several subprocesses with the same name, with Python3

Tags: shell, kill-process, pkill

With Raspberry Pi and Python3 I get these subprocess:

**ps -aux | grep python3**

```
pi    4168  0.9  0.7  11088  7304 ?     S    18:31   0:00 python3 blue.py
pi    4175  1.2  0.7  11088  7300 ?     S    18:33   0:00 python3 blue.py
pi    4185  2.4  0.7  11092  7300 ?     S    18:35   0:00 python3 blue.py
pi    4195  6.5  0.7  11088  7300 ?     S    18:38   0:00 python3 green.py
```

I need kill all **python3 blue.py** (**from Python**) and get...

**ps -aux | grep python3**

```
pi    4195  6.5  0.7  11088  7300 ?     S    18:38   0:00 python3 green.py
```

Comment: Do you have access to `pkill`?

Comment: Thank you Brad, I think pkill can work for me. os.system("pkill -f 'python3 blue.py' ")

Comment: Other way (terminal): ps aux | grep - ie 'python3 blue.py' | awk '{print "kill -9 " $2}' | sh -x

Answer (score 0):

for centos7 i use

```
pkill -f "Process name"
```

[image]